# ADB: Check connection type on device

Tags: java, android, junit, adb

I need to know if my adb connection is over USB or TPC/IP. Is there any way to check this status on connected device?
I can have situation when USB is connected, but still adb is over Ethernet.

I tried checking charge status. This could be fine, but still I can connect over Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
adb devices -l
```

and it shows `usb` or `tcp` (*in most of the cases*) and the `trasnport_id` that would be useful to use with `adb -t <id>`

#### edit

If you want to know if the device is connected using `adb` over wi-fi  you can do this (*assuming you don't know the port, otherwise is fairly trivial*).

Find the listening ports on the external network:

```
$ netstat -ltnp | grep LISTEN | grep -v 127.0.0.1
```

Hopefully you have only one, unless you have installed apps that open ports.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::42678                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Then, check the established connections on that port

```
$ netstat -tnp 2>/dev/null | grep 42678
```

and you eventually will find the connected `adb` via its IPv4-mapped IPv6 address:

```
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:<lipm46>:42678 ::ffff:<ripm46>:63333 ESTABLISHED -
```

Comment: I Need to check this on device side. Use case is I'm running instrumentation tests on device and depends how I connect USB or TCP I want to do certain actions. Whole logic I need on Android.

Comment: Interesting, Can you briefly describe what you are testing and how it depends on the adb transport?

Comment: Yes. My device can work in two modes. Host and Device. When I run test over USB and switch mode during it performs reset on USB that breaks connections and disconnects. When it's connected over Ethernet same reset is executed, but connection is not interrupted, because this is only on USB layer.

Comment: Got it, if you reset usb adb is disconnected.

Comment: Almost perfect. Still you can have situation when you connect over wifi (adb connect) and run tests over USB. But this also help. Thanks!

Comment: If you detect the device is connected over wifi just don't run the tests over usb, treat it as a pre-condition.